# Redirect Loop for WordPress on Google App Engine

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, redirect

I'm very newbie in Google App Engine. This is my first time running the application. so I basically follow this "Running WordPress in App Engine" https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress line by line.

I believe, I have successfully completed all the steps until step 8. Deploy. My local WordPress is working fine. WordPress is up and I can login Wp-admin. Then I deployed it. The log shows everything is great. Then I go to  my application. http://smart-road-562.appspot.com/wordpress and it shows Redirect Loop error

The webpage at .../wordpress/wp-admin/install.php has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

I have already added .htaccess with basic version as WordPress suggested in the document.

I have Google and searched everything and I still don't find any solution. I've been struggling on this issue for the past few days. I have tried deleting my project and instance on App Engine. If anyone has any suggestion, please please help

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

if you request

```
http://smart-road-562.appspot.com/wp-admin/install.php
```

directly you will get past the loop.  Your `app.yaml` probably needs another handler for the request with `wordpress` in it.